# UITextField not showing up on View Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I've added a simple UITextView and i placed it where i want to in the storyboard, then i click on add missing contraints/reset to suggested and it doesn't show up on the screen when i run it, i don't know why its not working

this is what i get in the debugger.

> Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
>           Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
>       (
>           "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x15ed61540 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x15eee5f50(20)]>",
>           "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x15ed0c500 V:|-(0)-[_UILayoutGuide:0x15eee5f50]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x15eee5df0 )>",
>           "",
>           "",
>           "" )
>
> Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint
>
> Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
>       The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in  may also be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Using the "add suggested constraint" is usually not a good idea. I really recommend that you study more about auto-layout and adaptive layout. I'd need to know exactly how you want to position and size you UITextField to determine what is the conflicting constraint for your case, it would be important to know what other views you have in your view controller that might be affecting the text field.

Comment: i dont have anything else in the view, just that. Also i just want it to be at the top of the view in the center

Comment: RayWenderlich.com is a good source. Check this link out. http://www.raywenderlich.com/113768/adaptive-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-getting-started

Comment: would that tutorial work still if im not using swift nor using universal? im using wCompact hRegular